# Need advice on optimizing database on a recurring basis

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a search engine with approx 3.5 million rows in the searchable table. There are many suppliers that feed into the table each day, so primary keys are constantly being removed and added and the fulltext column needs to be reindexed.

So I run an "optimize table" each day otherwise the search gets slow from all of the table updates.

Is there a way to constantly be updating the table, adding and deleting millions of rows without the indexes getting messy and the fulltext search getting slower?

Comment: With your level of changes, and the trades off of transactions vs. search, have you considered using MySQL/InnoDB as a backend and sphinx as a search engine: http://www.slideshare.net/spil-engineering/spil-gamesperconalivelondon2014sphinxsearchtitle ? You can stream the changes and update the indexes more or less "in real time".